# Data from ListBox to DataSet

Tags: delphi, listbox, dataset

I have `DBGrid` where I load names from `DataSetPeople` associated to `table_people`. I create a Drag and Drop procedure, where the user can drag a name and drop into a `ListBox`. The user can drop into a `listbox_employees` or `listbox_manager`.

**MY PROBLEM**

I want to create a relationship between people from `table_people` using the names that user drop in both listbox. I create `table_relationship` where `employeeID` match with `managerID`.

So, how can I get the name from each `listbox`, associate this name to an ID, and put this ID into a `employeeID` or `managerID` from `DataSetRelationship` associated to `table_relationship` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your IDs are numeric (integer) values, you can use the `TListBox.Items.Objects` to store it when you fill it (in your drop event handler on the form):

```
var
  PersonName: string;
  PersonID: Integer;
begin
  with YourDataModule do  // Gives access to the tables in the data module
  begin
    PersonName := table_people.FieldByName('employeeName').AsString;
    PersonID   := table_people.FieldByName('employeeID').AsInteger);
  end;
  listbox_employees.Items.AddObject(PersonName, TObject(PersonID);
end;
```

For the manager, just change to the listbox for the manager and the field values for the manager.

To get the ID back out to use for an `INSERT` statement:

```
// Make sure both listboxes have the same number of items, of course.
var
  EmployeeID: Integer;
  ManagerID: Integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ListBox_Employees.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    EmployeeID := Integer(ListBox_Employees.Items.Objects[i]);
    ManagerID := Integer(ListBox_Manager.Items.Objects[i]);
    if not YourDataModule.MakeRelationship(EmployeeID, ManagerID) then
      ShowMessage('Unable to relate this employee and manager!');
  end;
end;

// If you're using a SQL query, the `INSERT` should be created like this
// somewhere, like in your datamodule's OnCreate event
//   qryRelationShips.SQL.Clear;
//   qryRelationShips.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO table_relationship (employeeID, managerID)');
//   qryRelationShips.SQL.Add('VALUES (:employeeID, :managerID)';
//
// Or you can type it into the SQL property in the Object Inspector at designtime 
//   INSERT INTO table_relationship (employeeID, managerID) VALUES (:employeeID, :managerID)


function TYourDataModule.MakeRelationship(const EmpID, MgrID: Integer):  Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  // INSERT into your dataset:
  qryRelationShips.ParamByName('employeeID').AsInteger := EmpID;
  qryRelationShips.ParamByName('managerID').AsInteger := MgrID;
  try
    qryRelationShips.ExecSQL;
    Result := qryRelationShips.RowsAffected;
  finally
    qryRelationShips.Close;
  end;
end;

// If you're using a table instead of a query, getting a result is harder
function TYourDataModule.MakeRelationship(const EmpID, MgrID: Integer):  Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  try
    tblRelationShips.Insert;
    tblRelationShips.FieldByName('employeeID').AsInteger := EmpID;
    tblRelationShips.FieldByName('managerID').AsInteger := MgrID;
    tblRelationShips.Post;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have made tables using SQLite database. So what you want to do is possible by using a query to insert the rows. Use db.execSQL();
You can keep a counter for incrementong the id values.

Comment: I'm using IBExpert(Firebird). Do not need a counter, employeeID is PK and FK, it is the same ID from table_people. In this way, the user can't associate more than one manager to the same employee.